# How can i add css class to a specific li with a regex. which matches the text and assign only to the parent li which holds the matched set

Tags: jquery

**i have two css classes**

```
file
folder
```

Here what i want is to
**add a file class to the li which holds the link to the text file**
and folder class to other all li.

```
demo1
**final-project.txt**
demo2
**semi-final-project.txt**
```

Thanks for all help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $('a').each(function() {
     $(this).parent().addClass('folder')
 });
 $('a[href*=".txt"]').each(function() {
     $(this).parent().removeClass('folder').addClass('file');
 });
```

Comment: i tried it but it is assigning folder class to all li not affecting the .txt holder li.

Comment: sorry for that.. I've change `a[src` with `a[href` and now should work.. I've also edited my answer

Comment: check out this jsfiddle and please try to use firebug for verifying the results http://jsfiddle.net/BjEwx/

Comment: SORRY  Matei Mihai, it was my mistake in the markup generation from php code. Your code works THANKS VERY MUCH.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what is a file when you populate the list then I'd assign the class at that point. If for some reason you don't know that you could use the ':contains' or *= selector.

```
  $('a[href*=".txt"]').parent().addClass('file');
  $('li').not('.file').addClass('folder'); // Add folder class to all list items without class file.
```